# error CS0103: The name 'WebCamTexture' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc, windows-mixed-reality, magic-leap

When i build my project with WebRTCVidechat to a magicleap hardware it abort the operation and send a log error message saying "`Assets\WebRtcVideoChat\scripts\UnityCallFactory.cs(1073,37): error CS0103: The name 'WebCamTexture' does not exist in the current context`".

No copiler error apears before the build is made.

Part Of The Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
        foreach (var dev in WebCamTexture.devices)
                {
                    if (deviceName == dev.name)
                    {
                        if (dev.isFrontFacing)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Logs:

Assets\WebRtcVideoChat\scripts\UnityCallFactory.cs(1073,37): error CS0103: The name 'WebCamTexture' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: you have not in any way set the variable "WebCamTexture"

Comment: If line 1073 is the foreach loop you showed us, then the problem is that you have not declared the variable. Make sure you do so, and if you do, then show us the line. If WebCamTexture is a built in feature in unity, then you have either spelled it wrong, or you need to add an extra `using UnityEngine.something`.

Comment: i didn´t created that code, it is from pluggin code. 
the WebCamtexture,devices is found by my IDE as a normal list variable to me.

WebCamDevice[] WebCamTexture.devices { get; }
Return a list of available devices.

Comment: Well the plugin likely has a namespace. so you will need to use that

Comment: Yes, and i´m using it already. this code actually was already made by the creators, just trying to use it on build.

Comment: This problem only happens on build, on editor everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Error CS0103: The name 'WebCamTexture' does not exist in the current context" it´s caused by the incompatibility to the platform that i´m building for (MagicLeap).

I didn´t found any solution to fix it.